# Silex - UserProviderInterface always returns "Bad credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, silex

I am trying to add Users saved in a database to my Silex website using the SecurityProvider.

I registered the security provider

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array
(
    'admin' => array
    (
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'users' => function() use($app) 
        { 
            return new Entity\UserProvider($app); 
        }
    )
);
```

And the `Entity\UserProvider($app)` class goes as follow *(only part of the code is shown)*

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {     
        return new User('blabla', 'patate', ['ROLE_ADMIN'], true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

But even though i return a new User, and do not throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` the login page still gives me a `Bad credentials.` message.

Why am i getting this bad credentials message ? Did i forget something ? Did i mess up some config ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you add users to DB?

Comment: For now, there are no users, and no link to the database. I'm just trying to set up the User system with fake data before creating a link with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password encoder algorytms that are used in silex and on creating user differ.

Encoder in silex is set by parameter `security.default_encoder`

```
$app['security.default_encoder'] = function ($app) {
    return $app['security.encoder.bcrypt'];
};
...
$app['security.encoder.bcrypt'] = function ($app) {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder($app['security.encoder.bcrypt.cost']);
};
```

Use `bcrypt` for password encoding on user creation

```
return new User(
    'blabla',
    $app['security.encoder.bcrypt']->encodePassword('patate', ''),
    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    true, true, true, true
);
```

Or change silex encoder to plaintext (without encoding) to check if login works

```
$app['security.default_encoder'] = function ($app) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PlaintextPasswordEncoder();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max P. for your answer, you led me to the solution. You made me wonder why you would talk about password encryption while i was using fake data, so i checked what would happen if i used the exact same values everywhere.

The only problem was the fact that i used fake data. I assumed the data i was providing in the login form would go straight to oblivion, but in fact Silex makes sure the data from the form is matching the data in the returned User entity.

If it is not, it implicitly throws a "Bad credentials" error. (it would be nice if the silex logs would have told me that ...)